# Lazy Search is not working in Primefaces 7.0

Tags: primefaces

Map filters is getting the property as null in Primefaces 7.0 DataTable Lazy search.

I have upgraded from primefaces 5.0 to 7.0, the same code is working fine in 5.0.

I have a JSF page in which I'm using Primefaces DataTable and implemented the Lazy Search in the data table which is not working.

The thing is when I'm debugging this code I'm getting **null=123456789** as key/value in filters map. I wasn't able to understand why I'm getting null as the property value and because of which I'm getting

**java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.(StateHolderSaver.java:96)**

A snippet of Code in JSF page:

```
<p:dataTable id="d1" lazy="true" paginator="true"
    paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rendered="#{!bean.login}" rows="10"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" styleClass=""
    value="#{bean.lazyDataModel}" var="row"
    widgetVar="gridFilter" reflow="true">
        <p:column disabledSelection="false" exportable="false"
          resizable="false" toggleable="false">
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>
        <p:column disabledSelection="false" exportable="false"
           filterBy="#{row[0]}"
           headerText="#{bean.dataTableHeaderNames[0]}"
           resizable="false" toggleable="false">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:inputText onchange="PF('gridFilter').filter()"
                placeholder="Search" styleClass="textingrid" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel id="g1" value="#{row[0]}" />
        </p:column>

.........
```

here is the code for Lazy Model snippet:

```
@Override
    public List  load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters)
    {

       result=dbObject.lazyLoadList(first, pageSize, sortField, filters);

        return result;      
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the migration documents? Please do

Comment: I think `filterBy="#{row[0]}"` is not supported....

Comment: Any progress???

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue when migrating from 6.0 to 7.0 and it was fixed by upgrading to PrimeFaces 7.0.15 without changing anything in filter functionality.

Unfortunately any 7.x version is behind paywall (PrimeElite).